# Creating slope grid using Arc Hydro tools says dataset does not have spatial reference?

Tags: coordinate-system, arc-hydro

I am not able to create the slope grid using hydro tools. I am getting a error message saying that

> The dataset does not have spatial reference. Please specify a valid spatial reference

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common message in coordinate system Q&As here - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=dataset%20does%20not%20have%20spatial%20reference

I think it is unlikely to be related to Arc Hydro.

You need to use the [Define Projection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/define-projection.htm) tool to give it a Spatial Reference.

> Overwrites the coordinate system information (map projection and
>   datum) stored with a dataset. This tool is intended for datasets that
>   have an unknown or incorrect coordinate system defined.